# Selfhosted Gitlab Runner dind: How to cache docker images which are used in docker compose

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a self hosted gitlab, runner (15.x)
In the pipeline I'm using dind:20.x.x and run docker-compose directly in there.
The docker-compose uses images from the private gitlab repo.

```
test:
    image: docker:20.10.16
    stage: docker_test
    variables:
        DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
        DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
        DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    services:
        - docker:20.10.16-dind
    script:
        - echo "script starts"
        - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
        - docker compose -f docker-compose-cicd.yml up -d
```

Each time when running the pipeline, during the `docker-compose up` it pulls the used images from the repo, which takes quite some time.

I've tried to cache the docker folder

```
    cache:
        - ../../../var/lib/docker
```

but with the `overlay2` storage driver, the layers are stored on the host itself, outside of `gitlab-runner`'s reach.

I tried to work with (docker compose: cache_from, cache_to)[https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/], along the lines:

```
variables: 
  ...
  CACHE_DIR: build-cache

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - ${CACHE_DIR}/

--cache-from "type=local,dest=./${CACHE_DIR}"
--cache-to "type=local,dest=./${CACHE_DIR}"
```

This brings new trouble as docker buildx isn't available in dind (?)

Is there a way to cache the docker image?